# Is it possible to restrict access to public folders in Exchange online?

Tags: exchange, public-folders

We're using Office 365 have some public folders defined in Exchange online. Is it possible to restrict access to them? I see where I can manage folder permissions from the web version of Outlook (Admin -> Exchange -> public folders). I can add and remove users and edit their permissions, but everyone who isn't listed still has full access.

Is there somewhere where I have to set default access to *none*?

Are we mis-using this feature because public folders are meant to be completely public folders? If so, what should we be using instead?

[image: Folder Permissions]

Comment: Yes;  Your suppose to use private folders.

Comment: @Ramhound I have no experience with Exchange but I'm stuck with the responsibility of providing support for it. The thought process of Microsoft's programmers seems to have little correlation with mine. If you can provide a little more information, I'd appreciate it. Where can I find private folders?

Comment: There must be somewhere a default rule like in exchange 2010. When you create there an new folder you get a default read permisson. Are those useres which are not listet are only able to read the folder or change them as well (delete or edit stuff)?

Answer (score 0):

Folder permissions - Manage - Default (edit) - set "No access". Should do. Then you plain grant access based on user/group instead of denying.